# SSRS 2008 report shrinks/squeezes on printing from printer, but works all right if I export

Tags: reporting-services, printing, formatting, ssrs-2008

I have a **SSRS 2008 RDL** report that I deploy on our report server. Things were all good until today, when all reports when printed directly from the report server appear squeezed and shrunk. The preview of the report in the report server is perfectly all right. **But printing it to the printer and an xps file changes the appearance of the reports.**

However if I export the report to Word or Adobe, doesnt seem to happen.

I am very sure that this report and all the other reports where printing correctly before, till we figured out this today.

I have noticed that this is not on a single pc, I tried running the same set of reports on two different PC's over the network, results are still the same, SHRUNK reports.

Unfortunately I cant upload a picture.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. I tried quite a few things like margins and fonts, but didnt help.

So RESTARTING the SERVER  on which these reports were hosted fixed them all. I dont know how and why but all my reports are printing as they shown in the preview.

Thanks